# IdentityServer4 Grant Type for Javascript Client (no UI) access authenticated API

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have a ASP.Net Core web application that uses Devexpress Javascript controls.

I have a .Net Core API project that is [Authorized]. The ASP.Net Core web application accesses the API project via grant type ClientCredentials passing in client id and client secret for authentication. This flow works fine.

My issue is the javascript controls (no UI level authentication) need to access the API and I cannot use ClientCredentials grant type as the client secret will be visible inside javascript.

What grant type to use? or How to make sure the javascript client accesses the API securely with authentication?

**Update 1:** What I am looking for is how a Jasavscript client with NO UI level authentication (no login screen) can access a private API securely?

Comment: What does `no UI level authentication` mean? Your javascript application works in browser, right?

Comment: The UI level authentication (user id and password) is done by the ASP.Net Coew Web app - which is all C# and the grant type used is Hybrid. The javascript client is separate from the ASP.Net Core web app.

Comment: Depends on if you have an Single page application or not.  Usually you use implicit grant type for Single Page Applications. There is a new recommendation here: auth0.com/blog/oauth2-implicit-grant-and-spa but I don't think you need to worry about that just yet IMO.  If not an SPA then hybrid flow as Ganu mentioned –

Comment: I think that the question is misleading. You have an ASP.Net Core web application (mvc?) with javascript functionality. How can there be a seperate javascript client as well, with *NO UI level authentication*? If the javascript doesn't run in iframe's it's part of the client and should be able to request the existing access token. Are you sure you are using client credentials to access the api? Since you can use the access token that is received after login of the user as well, including the refresh token logic.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `client_credentials` flow when: `1.` you don't have signed-in user context (like server to server communication) and `2.` you can use back-channel to keep secret in secure way. Back-channel here means back-end part of your application.

If your front-end works in the same app with ASP.NET Core (i.e. in the same domain or subdomain like `example.com` and `api.example.com`) you can use plain cookie authentication for domain `*.example.com`. If they work in different domains you should use `implicit flow`. There is no secret concept in implicit flow. Access token is returned in response directly. You don't have back channel here here so you can't use secret.

`frontend app` <--implicit flow--> `web backend` <--client credentials--> `api`

To avoid misunderstanding please see these video [OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=996OiexHze0)

`What I am looking for is how a Jasavscript client with NO UI level authentication (no login screen) can access a private API securely?` - You can't do something like this. I suppose your code is executed in browser since you can't use secret. You need to authenticate the js client on web backend based on cookie or bearer token. To get bearer token without secret you can use implicit flow. If your js app and web app share the same domain you can use cookie authantiocation.

Comment: Can you share more detail on how to send the secret via back-channel using javascript client in a secure way?

Comment: Doesn't implicit flow require only the client id?  So if anyone knows the client id they will be able to access it. new recommendation to not use implicit flow: https://www.scottbrady91.com/Angular/Migrating-oidc-client-js-to-use-the-OpenID-Connect-Authorization-Code-Flow-and-PKCE

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is the meaning of `NO UI level authentication` . If your javascript client want to access protected api , normally user will be redirected to Identity server4's login page to enter your credential , javascript client won't have the UI for authentication .

You can use Implicit flow or Authorization code flow with PKCE . The second one is recommend nowadays which provides key to identify client instead of client secret .

Answer (score 0):

I think i have understood the question correctly. Also, i am assuming:
1)You are an authenticated user and redirected to SPA in your asp.net core app after login. Now, you need the access token for the logged in user.
2) Your asp.net core itself is an identity server.

You can use [identity server tools][1] for this purpose.
[1]: https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/tools.html
This generates access token. Below is the sample code which i have. This is in Account Controller in Asp.net Core app.

```
[Authorize]
        public async Task<string> Token(string clientId)
        {
            //var client = _configurationDbContext.Clients.Include(x => x.AllowedScopes).SingleOrDefault(x => x.ClientId == clientId);
            var client = Config.GetClients().SingleOrDefault(x => x.ClientId == clientId);
            if (client == null)
                return null;

            var claimsIdentity = _userProfileService.GetUserClaimsIdentity(Convert.ToInt32(User.GetSubjectId()));

            var token = await _tools.IssueClientJwtAsync(
                clientId: clientId,
                lifetime: 3600,
                audiences: client.AllowedScopes.Select(x => x).ToArray(),
                additionalClaims: claimsIdentity.Claims
                );

            return token;
        }
```

From the javascript client, since the SPA is part of asp.net core web app, you can get the token like this:

```
axios.get('/Account/Token?clientId='+'YOUR CLIENT ID HERE').then(resp=>{ 
        token = resp.data;
});
```

Now, you can use this token as Bearer token to call your authenicated apis